# What is the name of configuration to change the background of line number VScode?

Tags: visual-studio-code

How to change color of that background?

[image: How to change color of that background?]

https://code.visualstudio.com/api/references/theme-color - there is a website where you can choose all setting for vscode colors.
I have found only setting to change color of (1,2,3,4,5...).
Can you help me to change a background of that part of editor?

Comment: Are you trying to change the background of the container that holds the line numbers?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It's called the gutter, and what you might be looking for is `editorGutter.background`.

Comment: Thank You, exactly what i mean.