# How to change this color in VSCode

Tags: visual-studio-code

I don't know what exactly this name is... I want to remove that blue dashed? lines... How can i do this?

[image: want to change this color or remove this blue line]

I tried searching what this option is. But couldn't find.

Comment: The thing behind the line number is called [gutter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65659354/what-is-the-name-of-configuration-to-change-the-background-of-line-number-vscode), maybe this will help finding the correct setting?

Comment: and the next question is how do I see a local diff of the file, you have to click on the gutter, so you have to enable it, if you use SCM, like you do, it is very handy

Answer (score 0):

It's showing changes vs. your committed code.  The option is "SCM: Diff Decorations Gutter Visibility".  SCM = Source Control Management, a.k.a. git.